# The images from my database are appearing as little small question marks

Tags: php, image, echo, uploader

```
// connects to database here

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `blob` WHERE `id`='$id'");
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    header("content-type: image/jpeg");
    echo $imageData;
}
else 
{
    echo "Error!";

}


<img src="showimage.php?id=1">
```

the images are then being shown through and image tag shown above but they just appear as small icons (the correct number for those listed in the database but not the actual image)

Comment: Remove the content-type header for a second; open `showimage.php?id=1` and see what error messages you are getting

Comment: where is $imageData initialized ? maybe $imageData = $data['column_with_image']; ?

Comment: If you view the data being sent, does it appear to be an image? For example, in hex, the first four bytes of a JPG image should be `ff d8`, which is the [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) of the JPG format.

Comment: If i remove the content type i dont get anything at all on showimage.php

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the `<img src="showimage.php?id=1">` and put it on a different page; you can't keep it in the same page since it causes the web server to send headers before your script is even executed; your `showimage.php` should **only** contain PHP code, nothing else.

Then, change your code like this :

```
$data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
header("content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $data["image"];
```

I assume that your row is called "image" from your previous question.

Also, don't ask multiple questions for the same problem, you already got several answers on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124141/images-from-database-wont-show-headers-already-sent/21124432).